# Getting php tips and tutorials as daily emails to improve the knowledge in php programming

Tags: php, lamp

Thanks for your time.

This question is related to php programming but not a programming question.I have a young team of php (LAMP + javascript) programmers.I want them to learn better coding and keep themselves updated with the latest advancements in web domain.

I was thinking if there was any web site which send daily emails about php questions / problems/ solutions to common problems/ tips which will practically help the people to spend 10-15 minutes daily and enjoy the learning.This will also kind  of automate the habit of self learning on daily basis.

There are lots of PHP forums and php tutorials website, I tried to google but I did not find any website which does what I am looking for.

Please let me know if you know such website.If you have any other ideas to achieve the goal are also welcome.

Comment: Just ask them to answer three questions daily on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I think an RSS reader would be better, so that your team can get a list of new articles related to PHP and/or programming.

Most blogs and sites have an RSS feed. Here is a list with some RSS feeds:

- feed://www.reddit.com/r/php/.rss
- feed://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.rss
- feed://www.reddit.com/r/coding/.rss
- http://news.ycombinator.com/rss
- feed://feeds.feedburner.com/codinghorror

Comment: They can subscribe to SO feeds as well. This question for example has a feed link, http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/3021043. Tags have feeds as well.

Comment: Let each of them search for a couple of RSS feeds themselves. This way, they all learn different things instead of all reading the same things. Also, it will make them more interested in something they found themselves than if you tell them to read something.

Answer (score 2):

Make them create a profile on StackOverflow and ask them to focus on PHP tagged question, maybe suggesting yourself the Q/A that you find most appropriate.

You can also check their improvements over time, checking the answers they give.

They will both read the answers of expert programmers, and exercise their knowledge by proposing answers and see them judged.

The only problem is that the most enthusiasts will risk to spend too much time on stack overflow!

Answer (score 2):

> keep themselves updated with the
>   latest advancements in web domain

I think in this very beginning, you should be their tutor and guide them yourself: collect some information about web development, create a schedule and a list with the most important topics you think they have to know. (Look at [this thread in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site) how many information about a "generic website" is important to know. It's not specific to php, but the security section for example is a must!)

Then, you can create the "tips website" by yourself. Create a blog - from tumblr to wordpress - and each day post something yourself. (Do this for a month or more, you are the only one capable of knowing how much time is needed for your team to become a little more experienced)

Then, after some time (with them having more experience), you make **them** post tips and tutorials to others in the same blog. This way they can improve code and writing skills, which are also important in development. (Trying to express yourself to others by writing is a great skill).  Doing this in an internal blog is a great step to them if they are a little afraid of creating SO profiles (You avoid the "public forum syndrome", "I'm inexperienced to post there", etc)

If you host your own blog, you can create challenges like creating plugins for the blog itself, trying to use a concept they learned ("create a plugin in wordpress using PHP5 OOP"), or something you think they have to practice.

You can search for open source software that needs help and make them create patches.

...and if you decide to create an open blog, and if it's successfull, we can use it as a great example of tutoring.

(More importantly: make them read a PHP book. Make a deadline to each chapter and exercies proposed in the book. If you can't afford to buy one to them, try [free ones](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp).)

Comment: Hi GmonC , Thanks for your detailed post.I received it very well.I am already trying some of your suggestions , and will try the ones which I am not.Actually, one of my important aim is to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly off topic, but you could have them spend that time in weekly one-hour informal (no-preparation) code reviews.  You just find some recently developed code and have the developer talk through it.  They can see the code that others on the team write and having to explain what they did will force them to be honest about problem areas.  It's even better if you have someone a little more senior to ask questions and prod at their weaknesses.

Answer (score 0):

I work with php|architect magazine - http://www.phparch.com/ - and we have both a regular steady stream of daily articles (available via RSS) and the monthly pdf of the magazine. It's not a perfect match for what you're looking for but a good starting point.

http://phpdeveloper.org/ is another good source. The lead guy behind it is sharp and gets a good sampling of news and information from all over the place.

Oh.. and find a local user group.  DCPHP is mine - http://dcphp.net/

Answer (score 0):

I have found this to be the way to go:

- Create **[google alert](http://www.google.com/alerts)** for PHP
- Subscribe to **[official php site](http://www.php.net/mailing-lists.php)**
- and i adore **[phpro.org](http://phpro.org/)**